# Response.Flush() only serve one connection

Tags: asp.net, httpwebresponse

UPDATE:

I have a Counter.aspx.cs

```
    private int counter = 0;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            counter++;
            Response.Write(counter+"<br>");
            Response.Flush();

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if (counter == 10)
                break;
        }

        Response.Write("End");
    }
```

And a Index.aspx

```
<script language="javascript">
      function getData() {         
          var url = "Counter.aspx"; 
          loadXMLDoc(url);
      }
      var req = false;

      function createRequest() {
          // branch for native XMLHttpRequest object        
          if (window.XMLHttpRequest && !(window.ActiveXObject)) {
              try {
                  req = new XMLHttpRequest();
              } catch (e) {
                  req = false;
              } // branch for IE/Windows ActiveX version        
          } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
              try {
                  req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
              } catch (e) {
                  try {
                      req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                  } catch (e) {
                      req = false;
                  }
              }
          }
      }

      function loadXMLDoc(url) {
          try {
              if (req) {
                  req.abort();
                  req = false;
              }

              createRequest();

              if (req) {
                  req.onreadystatechange = processReqChange;
                  req.open("GET", url, true);
                  req.send("");
              } else {
                  alert('unable to create request');
              }
          } catch (e) {
              alert(e.message);
          }
      }

      function processReqChange() {
          if (req.readyState == 3) {
              try {
                  ProcessInput(req.responseText);                                                         
                  if (req.responseText.length > 3000) {                          
                      getData();
                  }
              } catch (e) {
                  alert(e.message);
              }
          }
      }

      var lastDelimiterPosition = -1;

      function ProcessInput(input) {
          var outputZone = document.getElementById("outputZone");
          outputZone.innerHTML = input;
      }
</script>

    <body>    
        <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="javascript: getData()"/>      
        <span id="outputZone"></span>
    </body>
```

So, I open two browsers with the same URL ~/Index.aspx and click on the start buttons on both browsers at the same time, the browser which I clicked "start" first will begin counting 1... 10 End. Then only after the first browser finished counting, the second browser starts counting 1... 10 End. Is there a way to allow both browsers to begin counting at the same time?

Comment: Not a problem wih Response.Flush I would say. Might be an issue with the number of concurrent connections client-side or server side. Tried from 2 browsers ? Tried from 2 different client devices ?

Comment: Hi @jbl , thanks for responding to my question. I have updated my entry and tested with two browsers. As above mentioned is the output I received.

Comment: I do not encounter this issue using FF and IE as browsers, and a webform running on IIS 7.5